# cat multiple files in multiple folders via a loop

Tags: bash, cat, fastq

I have a set of files which have fastq.gz inputs (R3003_C0UH3ACXX_ATTACTCG_L005_R1_001.fastq.gz ) In these files the RXXXX numbers are not sequential. However I got all the folder names whch begin with R in a txt file , one in each line. Each folder has different number of *_R1 and  *_R2 files. I would like to merge them and I have used cat *_R1.fastq.gz and *_R2.fastq.gz indiviually to do this .But I have 500 samples and it is impossible to run them all like this by going into each individual folder and doing cat. How do I get to open each folder in the txt file, run cat to get the final RXXX.R1.fastq.gz and RXXXX.R2.fastq.gz for each folder with a loop?
My file name is R3.txt which lists the RXXX files and I tried

```
for i in cat R3 ; do cat $i*R1*.fastq.gz >$i\.R1.fastq.gz; done
```

But it doesn't do what I hoping

Comment: My first advice: make backups of all these files first.

Comment: _"I would like to merge them"_ : merge per-folder? or merge all from all folders to a final single file? _"numbers are not sequential"_ : does the order the files are concatenated in matter? such as non-sequential but in ascending number order? Your attempt is using "R1" files but you want to ignore "R2" files? or more like `*R1* > final.R1` and `*R2* > final.R2`?

Comment: Yes merge per folder. And for the order, I mean, they are in ascending order R3002, R3004 etc but not completely sequential. And I want both R1 and R2 merged final files.